# Bootstrap: How to show text in carousel indicators?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show text as a carousel indicators in bootstrap. The property `text-indent` is set to -999px for `.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target]` by default, I changed it 0. Here, is the code:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
         aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1" style="
            text-indent: 0;">Test Button</button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
         aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
         aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3"
         aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
   </div>

   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <!-- Some other content for this slide -->
         <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <!-- Some other content for this slide -->
         <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <!-- Some other content for this slide -->
         <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <!-- Some other content for this slide -->
         <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My requirement is to carousel slide with text as indicators. Can explain why is the content out of the box? and how to show text as indicators?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put "text" class on the button that contains text:

```
<button type="button" class="text">Test Button</button>
```

Then try this CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .carousel-indicators .text[data-bs-target] {
            width: auto;
            height: 20px;
            text-indent: 0;
        }
```

I hope this will work.